# fetch:undefined data getting from body parser (Express,node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, fetch

I am new to React js and node js .This is a simple problem but I don't know how to solve it.I am using fetch which is light weight to post data and receiving that data from bodyparser.But it always undefined
form.js

```
import React from 'react';
    import Fetch from 'whatwg-fetch';

    class Form extends React.Component{
       constructor(props){
           super(props);
           this.state = {
               value:'',
               posted:''
           }
       }

        onPost(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            // console.log(this.refs.email.value);
            // console.log(this.refs.name.value);
            if(this.refs.email.value && this.refs.name.value != ''){
               fetch('/post',{
                   method:'POST',

                   body:JSON.stringify({
                       email:this.refs.email.value,
                       name:this.refs.name.value
                   })
               })
            }
        }
        render(){
       console.log(this.state);
            return (
                <div>
                    <form className="postform" onSubmit={this.onPost.bind(this)}>
                        <label>Email Addres</label>
                        <input type="email" ref="email" className="form-control"/>
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" ref="name" className="form-control"/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Post To server</button>
                    </form>

                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default Form;
```

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';


const app = express();
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();



app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(express.static('./public'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));



app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
   res.render('index')

});

app.post('/post',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);//undefines
    res.send('Ok ')

});

app.listen(3000,err=>{
   if(err) throw err;
    console.log('Im In at 3000')
});
```

Comment: Are you getting proper value of name and email here: 

 body:JSON.stringify({
                       email:this.refs.email.value,
                       name:this.refs.name.value
                   })
?

Comment: Yes I checked it in console.log

Comment: what is your express.js version?

Comment: "express": "^4.14.0" @abdulbarik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Replace

> `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`

with

> `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());`

OR

> `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`